# jQuery add button attribute using closest method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the button for adding items to cart

```
<div class="title_6">
    <button class="btn my-cart-btn bt_cart btn-large btn-positive" 
    data-id="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>" 
    data-name="<?php echo $row['product_name'];?>" 
    data-summary="<?php echo $row['pres_name'];?>" 
    data-price="<?php echo $row['sales_price'];?>" 
    data-quantity="1" 
    data-image="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['photo_1'];?>"  
    >Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set **data-quantity** attribute of button using jQuery. As there are multiple items I'm using closest method. What I've tried-

```
$(this).closest('.title_6').find('button').attr("data-quantity", qty);
```

But its not working. How to do that properly ?

Update:
Here is the code for (+) button. What is tying to do, When (+) button .bt_3 is clicked I'll add attribute to another button "Add Cart"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.product_row').on('click', '.bt_3', function() {

var qty = $(this).closest('.title_5').find('input').val();
var qty_add = Number(qty)+Number(1);

$(this).closest('.title_5').find('input').val(qty_add);
$(this).closest('.title_6').find('button').attr("data-quantity", qty_add);

  });
});
```

HTML for (+) & (-) button along with Add Cart Button  for better understanding

```
<div class="title_5">
<button class="btn bt_1 btn-large btn-negative">-</button>
<input type="text" class="bt_2" value="1">
<button class="btn bt_3 btn-large btn-primary">+</button>
</div>
<div class="title_6">
<button class="btn my-cart-btn bt_cart btn-large btn-positive" data-id="<?php echo $row['product_id'];?>" data-name="<?php echo $row['product_name'];?>" data-summary="<?php echo $row['pres_name'];?>" data-price="<?php echo $row['sales_price'];?>" data-quantity="1" data-image="admin/upload/<?php echo $row['photo_1'];?>"  >Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `this` in the script?

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? Also, depending on what the data attribute is read by you may need to use `data('quantity', qty)` to set it, or it's also possible that changing the value when the event occurs is too late as the library which uses the value has already been instantiated. In any case we need a more complete example of the problem to help you debug it

Comment: We need to see the event where you use `$(this).closest('.title_6')` also the html that refers to `this`

Comment: If `this` is the button inside `.title_6`, you don't need the query at all, the button is just `this`. What ever `this`  is, it should be an element inside `.title_6`, as `closest` searches elements on the direct ancestors of the context element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Question updated with HTML & Code details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$(this).closest('.title_6').find('button').attr("data-quantity", qty_add);
```

for this one:

```
$(this).parent().next('.title_6').find('button').attr("data-quantity", qty_add);
```